# Importing multiple configurable item sets into Magento using Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I have ~1100 unique configurable item sets that I want to import into Magento, with ~400 unique attribute sets. I am using Magmi with the configurable attributes plugin set.

The problem is, I only manage to import *one* configurable set. When I attempt to do multiple sets (which implies that I must use a new header row for each set) it only uploads the first set.

Here is the CSV that I am trying to import.

```
"sku","name","attribute_set","visibility","type","price","configurable_attributes","item","awer","simples_skus"
"BDM0557.01","Tee-Pants XS","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","XS","7",""
"BDM0557.02","Tee-Pants S","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","S","3",""
"BDM0557.03","Tee-Pants M","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","M","6",""
"BDM0557.04","Tee-Pants L","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","L","2",""
"BDM0557.05","Tee-Pants XL","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","XL","8",""
"BEDFER","Tee-Pants","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Catalog, Search","configurable",1000.00,"item,awer","","","BDM0557.01,BDM0557.02,BDM0557.03,BDM0557.04,BDM0557.05"
"sku","name","attribute_set","visibility","type","price","configurable_attributes","grit","colour","simples_skus"
"AFE3521.01","Waters XS","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","344","Red",""
"AFE3521.02","Waters S","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","621","Red",""
"AFE3521.03","Waters M","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","621","Green",""
"AFE3521.04","Waters L","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","344","Blue",""
"AFE3521.05","Waters XL","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","344","Orange",""
"REEADR","Waters","Newthing","Catalog, Search","configurable",1000.00,"grit,colour","","","AFE3521.01,AFE3521.02,AFE3521.03,AFE3521.04,AFE3521.05"
```

How can I get this to work, such that both sets are uploaded?

Comment: This question isn't programming related. It should be posted on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Apparently Magmi only accepts one header row and requires all of the attributes to be specified in that row.

This works:

```
"sku","name","attribute_set","visibility","type","price","configurable_attributes","item","awer","grit","colour","simples_skus"
"BDM0557.01","Tee-Pants XS","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","XS","7","","",""
"BDM0557.02","Tee-Pants S","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","S","3","","",""
"BDM0557.03","Tee-Pants M","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","M","6","","",""
"BDM0557.04","Tee-Pants L","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","L","2","","",""
"BDM0557.05","Tee-Pants XL","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","XL","8","","",""
"BEDFER","Tee-Pants","1/8 Inch Shank Mandrels","Catalog, Search","configurable",1000.00,"item,awer","","","","","BDM0557.01,BDM0557.02,BDM0557.03,BDM0557.04,BDM0557.05"
"AFE3521.01","Waters XS","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","","","344","Red",""
"AFE3521.02","Waters S","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","","","621","Red",""
"AFE3521.03","Waters M","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","","","621","Green",""
"AFE3521.04","Waters L","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","","","344","Blue",""
"AFE3521.05","Waters XL","Newthing","Not visible individually","simple",90.00,"","","","344","Orange",""
"REEADR","Waters","Newthing","Catalog, Search","configurable",1000.00,"grit,colour","","","","","AFE3521.01,AFE3521.02,AFE3521.03,AFE3521.04,AFE3521.05"
```